# CNN Text Classification Predicts labels for Ranking

Tags: keras, text, classification, conv-neural-network

I want to rank to classification label.

for examples I have a 5 news labels(sports, entertainment, politics, social, world). then, I predicts the sentences that is "LA Lakers became a basketball champion."

I want this result.

result : rank 1 sports
rank 2 entertainment
rank 3 social
.....

```
def sentence_classification(sentence):
  sentence_morpheme = morphs(sentence)
  seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([sentence_morpheme])
  train_label_vector() #labels
  padded = pad_sequences(seq, maxlen=max_len)
  preds = model.predict_proba(padded)[:,4]
  print(preds)
  index = np.argmax(preds)

  label = label_encoder.classes_[index]

  result = {sentence: label}
  return result
```

Thank you.

Comment: where's your model? where's your training/test data?

Comment: I trained model. I want to distribute the labels for predict.

Comment: If you want anyone to help, you need to supply some sample data, the model, etc. Show what output you are getting and your expected output